# How to cancel a javascript function if the user scrolls the page

Tags: javascript, scroll

Using this javascript to scroll to a div (#Content) after a 5s delay using setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Content').offset().top - 0 }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

How would I go about cancelling this action if the user scrolls manually before the 5s is elapsed. Reason being if the user has scrolled they'll be annoyed if the page then auto scrolls.

Tried putting it in window.load and checking for if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) but of course that's always true at window.load, and isn't cancelled by the user scrolling manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for example global variable and check if its set up by event scroll

```
var scrolled = false;
$(document).scroll(function(){scrolled = true;});
setTimeout(function () { 
 if (!scrolled){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Content').offset().top - 0 }, 
    1000); }
  }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall define your timeout into a variable to be able to cancel it with clearTimeout

See full documentation here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Just add an event to check oyur scroll and cleart your timeout if scrolled

For example :

```
var myVar = setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Content').offset().top - 0 }, 1000); 
}, 5000);
```

and to cancel your scroll :

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
 clearTimeout(myVar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the logic for checking the scroll by adding an event hanlder for `scroll` and then removing the event handler once it is done checking as it needs to be run only once. Also, You can clear the setTimeout by using the clearTimeout in the eventHandler Code.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEventHandler);

function scrollEventHandler(e){
    clearTimeout(...setTimeoutid) // Pass in setTimeout Id.    
}

setTimeout(function () {
         $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Content').offset().top - 0 }, 1000);
         window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollEventHandler);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the timeout as others have shown, or you can let it run but perform the scrollTop check inside before starting the scroll animation:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Content').offset().top - 0 }, 1000);
    }
}, 5000);
```